# Deconstructor, Dispose don't know what to use

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, garbage-collection, destructor, idisposable

I have run into a small issue in my program. I have a class with a Socket in it and some declared variables.

Now when i leave the page where the class was defined,

```
Class someclass = new class;
```

I want the class to be "destroyed", So that I can open a new socket with the same port/ip on a other page. (now the port and ip adress seems to be locked with the class i don't deconstruct/dispose/g.c)

Because I have a c++ background, and this is my first time using c#. I have no clue where to start, because in c++ you just call the destructor. This wil clean up your class and remove all active sockets/variables. But how do i accomplish this in c#. I have read some stuff about the Idisposable class but that doesn't make things clearer. Also there's the garbage collector and normal deconstructor. I don't know what to use, and more important how to use it.

---

Edit 1

As said below in the comments: this project is a windows phone project, that uses a external library for creating a socket and setting up communication between the windows phone and a Beckhoff PLC.

I've created an extra layer on top of the original library to make my variables easier to declare. the extra layer look likes this:

```
public class TwincatVar<T> : IDisposable where T : IConvertible
{

    public AdsClient _AdsClient;
    private string _PlcVar;
    private uint _VarHandle;
    private T _Data;
    private DateTime _TimeStamp;
    private bool disposed = false;
    public EventHandler DataChanged;

    //constructor
    public TwincatVar(ref AdsClient AdsClient, string PlcVar)
    {
        //Hook up to the reference of AdsClient
        _AdsClient = AdsClient;

        _PlcVar = PlcVar;

    }

    public async Task InitFunction()
    {

            _VarHandle = await _AdsClient.GetSymhandleByNameAsync(_PlcVar);

            Debug.WriteLine(_VarHandle.ToString());

            _Data = await _AdsClient.ReadAsync<T>(_VarHandle);

            _AdsClient.AddNotificationAsync<T>(_VarHandle, AdsTransmissionMode.OnChange, 1000, this);

    }


    public T Data
    {

        get { return _Data; }
        set
        {
            _Data = value;
            _AdsClient.WriteAsync<T>(_VarHandle, value);
        }
    }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get { return _TimeStamp; } }

    public void OnDataChangeEvent(T newData)
    {
        _TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        _Data = newData;

        //Raise the event
        if (DataChanged != null)
        {
            DataChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

}

/*
Noticed the : IDisposable  thats because i have allready tried to implement it, but that didn't work well.
*/

```
public class TwincatDevice : IDisposable
{
    public AdsClient AdsClient;

    //Twincatdevice constructor
    public TwincatDevice(string amsNetIdSource, string ipTarget, string amsNetIdTarget, ushort amsPortTarget = 801)
    {
        AdsClient = new AdsClient(amsNetIdSource, ipTarget, amsNetIdTarget, amsPortTarget);
        AdsClient.OnNotification += DistributeEvent;
    }

    public static void DistributeEvent(object sender, AdsNotificationArgs e)
    {
        AdsNotification notification = e.Notification;


        switch (Type.GetTypeCode((notification.TypeOfValue)))
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean: ((TwincatVar<bool>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((bool)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.Byte: ((TwincatVar<byte>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((byte)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.Int16: ((TwincatVar<short>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((short)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.Int32: ((TwincatVar<int>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((int)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.Single: ((TwincatVar<float>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((float)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.Double: ((TwincatVar<double>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((double)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.UInt16: ((TwincatVar<ushort>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((ushort)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.UInt32: ((TwincatVar<uint>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((uint)(notification.Value)); break;
            case TypeCode.String: ((TwincatVar<string>)notification.UserData).OnDataChangeEvent((string)(notification.Value)); break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the code below i declare my " twincat variables" which i connect to a datachange event. Also, these are connected to a " .name" variable on the plc.

```
 public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public TwincatDevice client;       
    public Device _device0;
    public Device _device1;
    public Device _device2;  
    public Devices DeviceList = new Devices();
    public TwincatVar<string> Version;

    //View Model
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        //Create devices with initual values
        _device0 = new Device("Device Name", "Status", "Version");
        _device1 = new Device("Device Name", "Status", "Version");
        _device2 = new Device("Device Name", "Status", "Version");

        //Add devices to observablecollection
        DeviceList.Add(_device0);
        DeviceList.Add(_device1);
        DeviceList.Add(_device2);

        // create the connection with the beckhoff device
        _Create_TwincatDevice();
        _Create_Twincatvars();
    }

    ~MainPageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void _Create_TwincatDevice()
    {
        // This is where the socket is openend !!

//Create TwincatDevice
        client = new TwincatDevice(amsNetIdSource: "192.168.11.216.1.1",
                                   ipTarget: "192.168.11.126",
                                   amsNetIdTarget: "192.168.11.126.1.1");        

    }

    public async Task _Create_Twincatvars()
    {
        // Create Twincat Variable
        Version = new TwincatVar<string>(ref client.AdsClient, ".Version");
        // Init Twincat Variable

        await Version.InitFunction();
        Version.DataChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { _device0.Version = Version.Data; });
        };



        // TwincatVar<type> Name = new TwincatVar<type>(reference to TwincatDevice, "Variable name PLC");

    }

}

}
```

And last but not least. In the " code behind the page" (mainpage.xaml.cs) I make an instance of the MainViewModel and set it to datacontext for binding.

```
private MainPageViewModel _MV;
_MV = new MainPageViewModel();
Device_listbox.DataContext = _MV.DeviceList;
```

I hope this helps so you guys can help me :)

Comment: Could you please show more source code on how the socket is created. Are you using any pointers to create a socket and connect to it? 
You can use Dispose pattern on your class which does socket stuff. In Dispose method you can put your clean up code. Then use Using() block over that class in the usage class.

Comment: @zenwalker Thats a bit of a problem, because the socket is created in a external library, and the only thing i do is declare a class in which the socket is created. The libary i use can be found here: 
http://ads.codeplex.com/

Its used to connect to PLC's using the ads protocol (on top of the normal socket in c#)

Comment: Yes please do show that code of how your using that API lib for creating, connecting and closing the sockets. Then we can help you more.

Comment: From `I leave the page`, should we guess you're using ASP.NET? Or is this a Windows application? Because if you're creating an ASP.NET project, the first problem will be to know when you're leaving a page... :-)

Comment: Ok i did read through this link http://ads.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Simple%20hello%20machine%20example&referringTitle=Examples and as per that he is using Using() block over the API. So that itself will clean up any opened sockets when the scope is over for that block. So just like that use it.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar, I'm making a windows phone 7.1 application in a normal page format (not pivot or panorama page). Also i'm trying to use the MvvM model to do so (just some extra backGround Information) I'll try to add some code on how i declare the class in a moment :)

But first i'll try the "Using" stuff :)

Comment: OK, it would be good if you edited your tags to indicate the "platform", too, as this may have influence on the tips you get ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I've update the tags, and added windows phone to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrast to C++, .NET doesn't allow the explicit destruction of an instance allocated by the garbage collector (classes and boxed value types/value types as members of an instance of a type allocated through the garbage collector). This because the Garbage Collector takes care of cleaning up after you when it deems nessesary (timed interval, memory pressure etc). If you need to release resources at the spot, you need to explicitly call a method. You can name this method something like Cleanup. .NET already comes with a well adopted pattern to do so. The method name is Dispose. (You c an implement a Dispose method with zero parameters and a void return type, or simply implement the IDisposable interface. Naming the method as 'Dispose' rather than 'Cleanup' gives you better tooling support and allows the use of the 'using statement' in which you define the scope wherein your instance should be used and which automatically calls the Dispose method at the end of the scope block.

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.71).aspx for detailed information on implementing the Dispose method and a best practice of how to use it in combination with a Destructor (and inherently the garbage collector)

Comment: In addition to calling the method `Dispose`, you should also implement `IDisposable`.  If your class will be inheritable, common practice is to have an implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose(void)` call a protected `Dispose(bool)` function which does the actual disposal.